# How to move a figure to a desired position by linear interpolation

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glm-math

I want to move two figures to the origin and then move them back to their original positions.
So, I try to move each figure to the origin using linear interpolation, but the current position of the figure is unknown. This is because the vertices of each figure are transformed. Therefore, the conversion information is known, but the location is not. I want to move to the coordinates of the figure and the origin through linear interpolation, but how should I do it? Is there another way?

[image]

`

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <gl/glew.h> // 필요한 헤더파일 include
#include <gl/freeglut.h>
#include <gl/freeglut_ext.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <random>
#include <gl/glm/ext.hpp>
#include <gl/glm/glm.hpp>
#include <gl/glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
using namespace std;

GLchar* vertexsource, * lvertexsource, * fragmentsource; //--- 소스코드 저장 변수
GLchar* coord_vertexsource;
GLuint vertexshader, lvertexshader, fragmentshader; //--- 세이더 객체
GLuint coord_vertexshader;
GLUquadricObj * qobj;

GLuint VAO, VAO2, VBO, VBO_tornado, EBO;

GLvoid Reshape(int w, int h);
const double pi = 3.14159265358979;
GLfloat mx;
GLfloat my;
void convertDeviceXYOpenGlXY(int x, int y, float* ox, float* oy);
void special(int key, int x, int y);
random_device rd;
default_random_engine dre(rd());
uniform_real_distribution<float> d(-1.0, 1.0);
uniform_real_distribution<float> cd(0, 1.0);
GLuint s_program;
GLuint l_s_program;
GLuint coord_s_program;
bool draw_on[10]{ false };
GLfloat color[10][3];

static bool c_draw = false;
static bool p_draw = true;
static bool w_draw = false;
static bool depth_draw = false;
static int rotate_cw_x = 2;
static int rotate_cw_y = 2;
static int rotate_cw_a = 2;
static int rotate_cw_b = 2;
static int rotate_cw_r = 2;
static int key_down = 0;
static int reset = false;
static int l_scale = false;
static int r_scale = false;
static int l_p_scale = false;
static int r_p_scale = false;
static int who_translate = 0;
static int y_translate = true;
static int t_shape = 0;
static int tornado_flag = false;
static int ToPoint_flag = false;
int cross_shape[3][2];
int tdegree = 0;
float tradius = 0;


char* filetobuf(const char* file)
{
    FILE* fptr;
    long length;
    char* buf;
    fptr = fopen(file, "rb"); // Open file for reading 
    if (!fptr) // Return NULL on failure 
        return NULL;
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END); // Seek to the end of the file 
    length = ftell(fptr); // Find out how many bytes into the file we are 
    buf = (char*)malloc(length + 1); // Allocate a buffer for the entire length of the file and a null terminator 
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET); // Go back to the beginning of the file 
    fread(buf, length, 1, fptr); // Read the contents of the file in to the buffer 
    fclose(fptr); // Close the file 
    buf[length] = 0; // Null terminator 
    return buf; // Return the buffer 
}

void make_vertexShader()
{
    vertexsource = filetobuf("rvertex.glsl");
    lvertexsource = filetobuf("lvertex.glsl");
    coord_vertexsource = filetobuf("coord_vertex.glsl");
    //--- 버텍스 세이더 객체 만들기
    vertexshader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    lvertexshader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    coord_vertexshader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    //--- 세이더 코드를 세이더 객체에 넣기
    glShaderSource(vertexshader, 1, (const GLchar**)&vertexsource, 0);
    glShaderSource(lvertexshader, 1, (const GLchar**)&lvertexsource, 0);
    glShaderSource(coord_vertexshader, 1, (const GLchar**)&coord_vertexsource, 0);
    //--- 버텍스 세이더 컴파일하기
    glCompileShader(vertexshader);
    glCompileShader(lvertexshader);
    glCompileShader(coord_vertexshader);
    //--- 컴파일이 제대로 되지 않은 경우: 에러 체크
    GLint result;
    GLchar errorLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexshader, 512, NULL, errorLog);
        cerr << "ERROR: vertex shader 컴파일 실패\n" << errorLog << endl;
        return;
    }
    glGetShaderiv(lvertexshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(lvertexshader, 512, NULL, errorLog);
        cerr << "ERROR: vertex shader 컴파일 실패\n" << errorLog << endl;
        return;
    }
    glGetShaderiv(coord_vertexshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(coord_vertexshader, 512, NULL, errorLog);
        cerr << "ERROR: vertex shader 컴파일 실패\n" << errorLog << endl;
        return;
    }
}

void make_fragmentShader()
{
    fragmentsource = filetobuf("fragment.glsl");
    //--- 프래그먼트 세이더 객체 만들기
    fragmentshader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    //--- 세이더 코드를 세이더 객체에 넣기
    glShaderSource(fragmentshader, 1, (const GLchar**)&fragmentsource, 0);
    //--- 프래그먼트 세이더 컴파일
    glCompileShader(fragmentshader);
    //--- 컴파일이 제대로 되지 않은 경우: 컴파일 에러 체크
    GLint result;
    GLchar errorLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentshader, 512, NULL, errorLog);
        cerr << "ERROR: fragment shader 컴파일 실패\n" << errorLog << endl;
        return;
    }
}

void InitShader()
{
    make_vertexShader(); //--- 버텍스 세이더 만들기
    make_fragmentShader(); //--- 프래그먼트 세이더 만들기
    //-- shader Program
    s_program = glCreateProgram();
    l_s_program = glCreateProgram();
    coord_s_program = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(s_program, vertexshader);
    glAttachShader(l_s_program, lvertexshader);
    glAttachShader(coord_s_program, coord_vertexshader);

    glAttachShader(s_program, fragmentshader);
    glAttachShader(l_s_program, fragmentshader);
    glAttachShader(coord_s_program, fragmentshader);

    glLinkProgram(s_program);
    glLinkProgram(l_s_program);
    glLinkProgram(coord_s_program);
    //--- 세이더 삭제하기
    glDeleteShader(vertexshader);
    glDeleteShader(lvertexshader);
    glDeleteShader(coord_s_program);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentshader);
}

struct pos {
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat z;
    GLfloat r;
    GLfloat g;
    GLfloat b;
};

vector<pos> tornado;

void InitBuffer()
{

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,     1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0,      1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,      0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, -1.0, 0.0,     0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, -1.0,     0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,      0.0, 0.0, 1.0,

        -0.1, -0.1, -0.1,   1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
         0.1, -0.1, -0.1,   0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
         -0.1, -0.1, 0.1,   0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
         0.1, -0.1, 0.1,    1.0, 0.0, 1.0,

         -0.1, 0.1, -0.1,   1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
         0.1, 0.1, -0.1,     0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
         -0.1, 0.1, 0.1,    0.5, 0.0, 1.0,
         0.1, 0.1, 0.1,      0.0, 0.5, 1.0,
    };

    unsigned int index[] = {
        0, 1, 
        2, 3,
        4, 5,

        6, 7, 8, // 아랫면
        7, 9, 8,

        10, 13, 11, // 윗면
        10, 12, 13,

        11, 13, 7, // 우측면
        7, 13, 9, 

        10, 6, 8, // 왼쪽면
        10, 8, 12, 

        8, 9, 12, // 뒷면
        9, 13, 12, 

        11, 7, 6, // 앞면
        10, 11, 6,

        //================

        15, 17, 18,
        15, 16, 17,
        14, 15, 18, 
        14, 16, 15, 
        14, 17, 16, 
        14, 18, 17,
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO); //--- VAO 를 지정하고 할당하기
    glBindVertexArray(VAO); //--- VAO를 바인드하기

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(index), index, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    //=============================================================================================

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO2); //--- VAO 를 지정하고 할당하기
    glBindVertexArray(VAO2); //--- VAO를 바인드하기

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_tornado);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_tornado);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GL_FLOAT) * 3 * 400, &tornado[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

glm::mat4 R = glm::mat4(1.0f); //--- 회전 행렬 선언
glm::mat4 T = glm::mat4(1.0f); //--- 이동 행렬 선언
glm::mat4 TR = glm::mat4(1.0f); //--- 합성 변환 행렬
glm::mat4 S = glm::mat4(1.0f);

glm::mat4 CR = glm::mat4(1.0f); //--- 회전 행렬 선언
glm::mat4 CT = glm::mat4(1.0f); //--- 이동 행렬 선언
glm::mat4 CTR = glm::mat4(1.0f); //--- 합성 변환 행렬


glm::mat4 lR = glm::mat4(1.0f); //--- 회전 행렬 선언
glm::mat4 lT = glm::mat4(1.0f); //--- 이동 행렬 선언
glm::mat4 lTR = glm::mat4(1.0f); //--- 합성 변환 행렬
glm::mat4 lS = glm::mat4(1.0f);

GLvoid drawScene()
{
    //--- 변경된 배경색 설정
    glClearColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (!depth_draw)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    else
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    //--- 사용할 VAO 불러오기
    //--- 삼각형 그리기
    glBindVertexArray(VAO2);
    glUseProgram(coord_s_program);
    glPointSize(1);

    if(tornado_flag)
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 200);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glm::mat4 unit = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    CTR = CR * CT;
    unsigned int coord_modelLocation = glGetUniformLocation(coord_s_program, "coord_modelTransform");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(coord_modelLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(CTR));
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    if(!r_p_scale)
        TR = CR * T * R * S * CT;
    else
        TR = S * CR * T * R * CT;
    glUseProgram(s_program);
    unsigned int modelLocation = glGetUniformLocation(s_program, "modelTransform");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(TR));

    if (t_shape == 0)
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (GLvoid*)(sizeof(GLuint) * 6));
    else {

        gluCylinder(qobj, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 10, 8);
    }
    
    if (!l_p_scale)
        lTR = CR * lT * lR * lS * CT;
    else
        lTR = lS * CR * lT * lR * CT;

    glUseProgram(l_s_program);
    unsigned int lmodelLocation = glGetUniformLocation(l_s_program, "lmodelTransform");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(lmodelLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(lTR));

    if (reset) {
        CTR = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        CT = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        CR = glm::mat4(1.0f);

        CT = glm::translate(CT, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        CR = glm::rotate(CR, glm::radians(-45.0f), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        CR = glm::rotate(CR, glm::radians(45.0f), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));

        R = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        lR = glm::mat4(1.0f);

        rotate_cw_r = 2;
        rotate_cw_x = 2;
        rotate_cw_y = 2;
        rotate_cw_a = 2;
        rotate_cw_b = 2;
        reset = false;
    }

    qobj = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(qobj, GLU_LINE);
    //gluQuadricNormals(qobj, GLU_SMOOTH);
    //gluQuadricOrientation(qobj, GLU_OUTSIDE);

    if (t_shape == 0)
        gluSphere(qobj, 0.1, 20, 20);
    else
        gluCylinder(qobj, 0.1, 0.0, 0.2, 10, 8);


    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE);
    glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_LINE);

    glutSwapBuffers(); //--- 화면에 출력하기
}

GLvoid Reshape(int w, int h) //--- 콜백 함수: 다시 그리기 콜백 함수
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void Mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    convertDeviceXYOpenGlXY(x, y, &mx, &my);

    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)
    {
        
    }
}

void KeyUp(int z, int x, int y)
{
    key_down = 0;
}

void Keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case '3':
        r_p_scale = false;
        if (r_scale) {
            r_scale = false;
        }
        else
            r_scale = true;
        break;
    case '4':
        l_p_scale = false;
        if (l_scale)
            l_scale = false;
        else
            l_scale = true;
        break;
    case '5':
        if (r_scale) {
            r_p_scale = false;
            r_scale = false;
        }
        else {
            r_p_scale = true;
            r_scale = true;
        }
        break;
    case '6':
        if (l_scale) {
            l_p_scale = false;
            l_scale = false;
        }
        else {
            l_p_scale = true;
            l_scale = true;
        }
        break;
    case '1':
        who_translate = 1;
        break;
    case '2':
        who_translate = 2;
        break;
    case '0':
        who_translate = 0;
        break;
    case 'y':
        if (y_translate)
            y_translate = false;
        else
            y_translate = true;
        break;
    case 's':
        reset = true;
        break;
    case 'r':
        if (tornado_flag) {
            tornado_flag = false;
        }
        else {
            tdegree = 0;
            tradius = 0;
            tornado_flag = true;
            CT = glm::mat4(1.0f);
            CT = glm::translate(CT, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

            T = glm::mat4(1.0f);
            T = glm::translate(T, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

            lT = glm::mat4(1.0f);
            lT = glm::translate(T, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        }
        break;
    case 't':
        if (ToPoint_flag)
            ToPoint_flag = false;
        else
            ToPoint_flag = true;
        break;
        break;
    case 'q':
        exit(1);
        break;
    }
}

void special(int key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
    {
        key_down = 1;
    }
    if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
    {
        key_down = 2;
    }
    if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP)
    {
        key_down = 3;
    }
    if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
    {
        key_down = 4;
    }
}


void TimerRotateTornado(int Value) {
    float rotate_x = tradius * sin(tdegree / 360.0 * 2 * pi);
    float rotate_z = tradius * cos(tdegree / 360.0 * 2 * pi);

    if (tornado_flag) {
        T = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        T = glm::translate(T, glm::vec3(rotate_x, 0.0, 0.0));
        T = glm::translate(T, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, rotate_z));

        lT = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        lT = glm::translate(lT, glm::vec3(-rotate_x, 0.0, 0.0));
        lT = glm::translate(lT, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, -rotate_z));
    }

    tdegree += 10;
    tradius += 0.005;
    if(tradius < 1)
        glutTimerFunc(100, TimerRotateTornado, 2);
}

void TimerFunction(int value)
{
    static float rotate_value = 0.1;
    static float rcnt = 1.001;
    static float lcnt = 1.001;
    static float rtemp_value = 1.0;
    static float ltemp_value = 1.0;

    if (r_scale == true) {
        rtemp_value += rcnt - 1;
        S = glm::scale(S, glm::vec3(rcnt));
    }
    if (l_scale == true) {
        ltemp_value += lcnt - 1;
        lS = glm::scale(lS, glm::vec3(lcnt));
    }

    if (rtemp_value >= 1.5)
        rcnt = 0.999;
    if (rtemp_value <= 1.0)
        rcnt = 1.001;

    if (ltemp_value >= 1.5)
        lcnt = 0.999;
    if (ltemp_value <= 1.0)
        lcnt = 1.001;
        
    if (key_down != 0)
    {
        switch (key_down) {
            {
        case 1:
            if (who_translate == 0)
                CT = glm::translate(CT, glm::vec3(-0.005, 0.0, 0.0));
            if (who_translate == 1)
                T = glm::translate(T, glm::vec3(-0.005, 0.0, 0.0));
            if (who_translate == 2)
                lT = glm::translate(lT, glm::vec3(-0.005, 0.0, 0.0));

            break;
        case 2:
            if (who_translate == 0)
                CT = glm::translate(CT, glm::vec3(0.005, 0.0, 0.0));
            if (who_translate == 1)
                T = glm::translate(T, glm::vec3(0.005, 0.0, 0.0));
            if (who_translate == 2)
                lT = glm::translate(lT, glm::vec3(0.005, 0.0, 0.0));
            break;
        case 3:
            if (who_translate == 0)
                CT = glm::translate(CT, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.005));
            if (who_translate == 1) {
                if (!y_translate)
                    T = glm::translate(T, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.005, 0.0));
                else
                    T = glm::translate(T, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.005));
            }
            if (who_translate == 2) {
                if (!y_translate)
                    lT = glm::translate(lT, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.005, 0.0));
                else 
                    lT = glm::translate(lT, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.005));
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            if (who_translate == 0)
                CT = glm::translate(CT, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, -0.005));
            if (who_translate == 1) {
                if (!y_translate)
                    T = glm::translate(T, glm::vec3(0.0, -0.005, 0.0));
                else
                    T = glm::translate(T, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, -0.005));
            }
            if (who_translate == 2) {
                if (!y_translate)
                    lT = glm::translate(lT, glm::vec3(0.0, -0.005, 0.0));
                else
                    lT = glm::translate(lT, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, -0.005));
            }
            break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(rotate_cw_x == 0)
        R = glm::rotate(R, glm::radians(rotate_value), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    else if(rotate_cw_x == 1)
        R = glm::rotate(R, glm::radians(-rotate_value), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    else if (rotate_cw_y == 0)
        R = glm::rotate(R, glm::radians(rotate_value), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    else if (rotate_cw_y == 1)
        R = glm::rotate(R, glm::radians(-rotate_value), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));

    if (rotate_cw_a == 0)
        lR = glm::rotate(lR, glm::radians(rotate_value), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    else if (rotate_cw_a == 1)
        lR = glm::rotate(lR, glm::radians(-rotate_value), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    else if (rotate_cw_b == 0)
        lR = glm::rotate(lR, glm::radians(rotate_value), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    else if (rotate_cw_b == 1)
        lR = glm::rotate(lR, glm::radians(-rotate_value), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));

    if (rotate_cw_r == 0) {
        CR = glm::rotate(CR, glm::radians(rotate_value), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    }
    else if (rotate_cw_r == 1) {
        CR = glm::rotate(CR, glm::radians(-rotate_value), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    }

    InitBuffer();
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(1, TimerFunction, 1);
}



void TimerToPoint(int value) {
    
    /*if (ToPoint_flag == true)
        T = glm::translate(T, glm::vec3(-0.002, 0.0, 0.0));*/

    glutTimerFunc(10, TimerToPoint, 3);
}

void convertDeviceXYOpenGlXY(int x, int y, float* ox, float* oy)
{
    int w = 800;
    int h = 600;
    *ox = (float)(x - (float)w / 2.0) * (float)(1.0 / (float)(w / 2.0));
    *oy = -(float)(y - (float)h / 2.0) * (float)(1.0 / (float)(h / 2.0));
}

void Init()
{
    CT = glm::translate(CT, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    CR = glm::rotate(CR, glm::radians(-45.0f), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    CR = glm::rotate(CR, glm::radians(45.0f), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));

    T = glm::translate(T, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.0, 0.0));

    lT = glm::translate(lT, glm::vec3(-0.5, 0.0, 0.0));

    double degree = 0;
    float radius = 0;
    GLfloat x = 0;
    GLfloat y = 0;
    GLfloat z = 0;
    GLfloat r = 0.5;
    GLfloat g = 0.3;
    GLfloat b = 0.1;
    

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
        x = radius * sin(degree / 360 * 2 * pi);
        z = radius * cos(degree / 360 * 2 * pi);

        tornado.push_back({x, y, z, r, g, b});
        degree += 10;
        radius += 0.005;

    }

}

void main(int argc, char** argv) //--- 윈도우 출력하고 콜백함수 설정
{
    //--- 윈도우 생성하기
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 800);
    glutCreateWindow("Example1");
    //--- GLEW 초기화하기
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    Init();
    glewInit();
    InitShader();
    InitBuffer();
    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
    glutMouseFunc(Mouse);
    glutKeyboardFunc(Keyboard);
    glutSpecialFunc(special);
    glutSpecialUpFunc(KeyUp);
    glutTimerFunc(100, TimerFunction, 1);
    glutTimerFunc(100, TimerRotateTornado, 2);
    glutTimerFunc(100, TimerToPoint, 3);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

`

i want to move object to origin

Comment: Interpolation is not a technique for moving (the formal term is translating) objects.

Comment: @Peter: How so? It works well enough if you understand _what_ you need to interpolate (coordinates). I.e. to move an object from x0 to x1 in the time interval [0,1], you interpolate x as function of t, e.g. for constant velocity `x= std::lerp(x0,x1, t)`.

Comment: @MSalters Interpolation is a technique for estimating values between data points.   One might use interpolation to work out what translation needs to be applied to an object.   It is not a technique for doing the translation.   Describing interpolation as a technique for moving or translating is confusing one concept with another.

Comment: @Peter: Ah, I see what you think. But I still think you're misreading the question. I think moving really means moving here, and not translation, specifically because then interpolation does make sense. Your reading substitutes a word by a word with a different meaning, and then the modified question no longer makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your projection appears to be a simple orthogonal projection, and in particular linear (in the spatial coordinates). This is quite convenient: it means you can do your interpolation before or after projection, and you will get the same results.

You just need to be consistent: If you're interpolating before projection, you use three-dimensional coordinates, with your origin by definition at `0,0,0`. If you're interpolating after projection, you use two-dimensional coordinates.

In your case, you're using OpenGL to do the projection, so it's easier to interpolate 3D coordinates.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know how to move the object to the origin. I want to move it slowly to the origin.

Comment: @백승호: I suspect you're a bit new to programming ? And the code in the question isn't yours? New programmers often find it difficult to break a larger problem in smaller, easy problems. They just get hung up on the initial problem. "move slowly" probably just means "in many small steps". So the obvious question would be, what would it mean to move _one_ small step? And then repeat that. This way, I've broken your problem in two parts.